# How can I fix First Layer Adhesion with BL Touch - Tevo Tarantula

Tags: marlin, bltouch, tevo-tarantula

Hope someone might have a view on where to go with this. My prints were coming out pretty good, but since installing a BL Touch to the printer I've been unable to get consistent first layer adhesion.

- Printer: Tevo Tarantula
- Firmware: Jim Brown Marlin

Settings:

- Speed: initial layer 30 mm/s others 60 mm/s
- Layer height: tried everything from 0.1 to 0.3 mm
- Temperatures

  - Nozzle temperature: 204 °C (stock hot end and nozzle)
  - Bed temperature: 60 °C

Printing Sunlu PLA+ filament onto Printbrite on the stock bed using bilinear Leveling (tried both 3 points and 5)

Z homes with the probe in the centre of the bed and the G29 command takes the readings ok.

I've configured Z offset so that you can barely move a sheet of paper between the bed and nozzle when you send G1 Z0. But it still looks like the nozzle is too far away from the bed when printing first layer.

I've managed to get a 20 mm calibration cube out of it, but that is inconsistent (the two cubes in the pictures were printed one after the other with no changes).

Anything bigger than that doesn't stick at the corners and ends up as a ball of spaghetti.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE!

Comment: What type of filament are you using? You mention the brand, but don't say what it is. Have you tried multiple filament types/brands?

Comment: Its 1.75mm PLA+ I've also used another brand of PLA with similar results. I've used this brand consistently with no issues before installing the BL Touch

Comment: it looks like your sensor is triggering inconsistently. is it an original BL-touch or one made of Chinesium?

Comment: nope, its an original - it does seem to complete the mesh ok, its just when it prints I can't get consistency in things sticking to the bed. Is it worth me trying to post a probing output?

Comment: Isn't is too close? The skirt is very thin. Are you sure the gap is too big?

Comment: it looks to me like it's both, the skirt and parts to the left of the model seem to be very squashed but the right hand side and back left corner aren't sticking to the bed.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same kind of issues I'm also using Sunlu white filament 210 °C and bed at 60 °C on a CR-10S also original BLtouch v3.1

On some parts of the bed it's okay but in the middle and some corners it's too high and doesn't stick (really annoying). I bought the BLtouch to avoid this kind of issues.

I have printed many things with no issues and with this filament It's making some trouble.

Ok I have solved the issue, the problem is Sunlu pla+ filament.

It seems that their filament is really hard to adhere to bed.

I found on another forum that you need to increase bed temperature up to 70° and head to 220 °c at least for the few first layers and don't go under 215°.

also moving the head a bit lower to skish the filament on bed.

I tried and got much better adhesion.

Hope it will help other people